# How to bend the border like slight crecent shape using css?

Tags: css

```css
#chevron {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 12px;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      height: 60px;
      width: 200px;
      border:1px solid red;
    }
    
    #chevron:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 20%;
      width: 100%;
      background: red;
      transform: skew(0deg, 0);
    }
```

```html
<div id="chevron"></div>
```

I tried but not works as expected.
[image: like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use border-radius instead of skew. Tweak the values of `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` to tweak the apex of the crescent.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border:1px solid red;
  border-top: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

#chevron-1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  border-top: 0px;
}

#chevron-2 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  border-top: 0px;
}


div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="chevron-1"></div>

<div id="chevron-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the `#chevron::after` pseudo-element on top of the `#chevron::before` element, give `#chevron::after` white background color and use `border-radius` on both pseudo-elements to make them curved like a crescent.

```css
#chevron {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

 #chevron::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: -8px;
   left: -1px;
   height: 25%;
   width: 101%;
   background: red;
   border-radius: 70%;
}

#chevron::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   left: -2px;
   height: 25%;
   width: 102%;
   background: #fff;
   border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="chevron"></div>
```